# How to add if-then expression into user-defined function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark

I have this user-defined function in python Spark:

```
result = udf(lambda num1, num2:  (num1 - num2) / math.sqrt(1-(num1/num2)), FloatType())
```

I want to add a check that `num1/num2` is greater than 1. If it's lower than 1, then `num1` should be equal to `num2`.

```
if (num1/num2 > 1): 
        num1 = num2
```

How can I add this simple check into `udf` expression?

I tried this, but it seems to fail:

```
def calculate(num1, num2):
    if (num1/num2 > 1): 
        num1 = num2
    result = (num1 - num2) / math.sqrt(1-(num1/num2))
    return result   
calc_z = udf(lambda num1, num2: calculate, FloatType())
```

Comment: `udf(calculate, FloatType())`, no need to wrap it incorrectly in a `lambda`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use where function to get the result as below

```
df.withColumn("result", when(($"num1" / $"num2") < 1, $"num2")
  .otherwise($"num1"))
```

Its always better to use available function rather than using UDF.

If you still want to use UDF you can register above your udf as

```
calc_z = udf(calculate, FloatType())
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why is it better ti use `withColumn` than `udf`? Does it influence the computational time?

Comment: Yes, Spark treats UDF as an blackbox and does not even bother to optimize it. Here is the details https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-sql-udfs.html

Answer (score 1):

You can have `num1` dynamically assigned in your case if you replace `num1` with:

`(num2 if num1/num2 > 1 else num1)`

Answer (score 1):

You need the function to be called in the lambda.

```
def calculate(num1, num2):
    if (num1/num2 > 1): 
        num1 = num2
    result = (num1 - num2) / math.sqrt(1-(num1/num2))
    return result   
calc_z = udf(lambda num1, num2: calculate(num1, num2), FloatType())
```

Not the change on the last line with calling calculate.

Edit (based on @bruno desthuilliers):

```
def calculate(num1, num2):
    if (num1/num2 > 1): 
        num1 = num2
    result = (num1 - num2) / math.sqrt(1-(num1/num2))
    return result   
calc_z = udf(calculate, FloatType())
```

Comment: You don't need the lambda at all - just pass `calculate` as the first argument.

Comment: I get this error `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level` when I execute your second code.

Comment: Check your tabs vs spaces. and make sure your tabs are correct. Copying and pasting code from online often messes up indents.

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda is returning a function that has not been called. Try this.

```
def calculate(num1, num2):
    if (num1/num2 > 1): 
        num1 = num2
    result = (num1 - num2) / math.sqrt(1-(num1/num2))
    return result   
calc_z = udf(calculate, FloatType()) # Changed this line
```